# how to make $page['content'] stop replacing HTML

Tags: theming

In my page (basic page content type) I have the following code in the body field

```
<h3 class="blue-txt">Heading</h3>
```

In my custom themes page.tpl.php I have

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

However the rendered content replaces the h3 with a p and stripes my class for some reason and I need it to render the code that I saved.

```
<p>header</p>
```

However, if I use the following then it will print correctly:

```
<?php print field_get_items('node', $node, 'body')[0]['value']; ?>
```

If I use that then when I navigate to any of the default pages, mainly the admin login I get an error as $node is not defined. I added a conditional to check that $node was defined to prevent the error. After that the error wasn't displayed but since $node was supposed to contain the content, no content is displayed.

What am I doing wrong here? I just need my page to print out the body without deciding it should edit my code for me and I don't understand why $page['content'] is butchering my code.

Comment: After looking at the array values for $page['content'] it looks like what is being displayed is the safe_value instead of the value. How can I tell drupal to use the value instead?

Comment: Ok, as you are using the body field I am assuming you are using a WYSIWYG, which one? The WYSIWYG module? You should not have to tinker with the tpl to get h3s to display. What are your allowed tags in Configuration > Content Authoring > WYSIWYG Profiles > Your_Profile?

Comment: I am using CKEditor for my wysiwyg.

Comment: I don't think ckeditor is the issue. In the editor my tags are being displayed correctly, I've already allowed the necessary tags in ckeditors filters. I just need to figure out how to render the value instead of the safe value

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `admin/config/content/formats/html` where 'html' is your WYSIWYG profile and check your **filter processing** order.

Mine:

Insert view filter
Convert Media tags to markup
CKEditor Link Filter
Convert URLs into links
Correct faulty and chopped off HTML
Limit allowed HTML tags

If I put 'Limit allowed HTML tags' at the top I get similar issues to what you are describing.

**EDIT:** The order did not actually cause the issue for me. I had just forgotten to add `<h3>` to the allowed list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the options under `Structure` > `Content Types` > `Basic page`  > `Manage Display` > `Body` field (format column).

Comment: The manage display format for body is "Default"